# MongoDB $group + $project + weekly average

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the average of a puntations for some stores weekly in Mongo but it don't work. Could u help me?

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$match:{storeId:{$in:[
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e235v"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9t7j8n"),
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e2fg6"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9p56r2") 
]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$storeId", week: { date: new Date("$createdAt")  }, totalPoints: {$sum: "$points"}, averagePoints: {$avg: "$points"}} },
    {$sort: {totalPoints:-1}}
])
```

It doesn't work. But if I delete the part of the week, the code work it but make a wrong average

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$match:{storeId:{$in:[
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e235v"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9t7j8n"),
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e2fg6"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9p56r2") 
]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$storeId", totalPoints: {$sum: "$points"}, averagePoints: {$avg: "$points"}} },
    {$sort: {totalPoints:-1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

For `groupBy` week you can use `$week` function from mongo and add start Date in `$match` operation.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$match:{storeId:{$in:[
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e235v"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9t7j8n"),
ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9e2fg6"),ObjectId("e069d1b76557685b9p56r2") 
]},
 timeStamp: {$gt: ISODate(createdAt)},
}},
{$group:{_id:"$storeId", week: { $week: '$timeStamp'}, totalPoints: {$sum: "$points"}, averagePoints: {$avg: "$points"}} },
    {$sort: {totalPoints:-1}}
])
```

Comment: @coget that send me an error: ReferenceError: createdAt is not defined